# How can I get the list of columns that have changed with respect to the previous row in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, etl, analytics

For a better understanding consider the example shown below and the image attached:

Suposing that none of the columns from a table in BigQuery should have changed from day 1 to day 2 when the ID is the same, how can I get the list of columns that did not behave as expected.

In other words, I woud like to list all the columns that HAVE CHANGED from day 1 to day 2 when the ID is the same.

In the last column of the example I'm presenting the desired outputs:

```
| ID | Day | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Desired outputs
| 1  | 1   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |     Column3
| 1  | 2   |    x    |    x    |    y    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |     Column3
| 2  | 1   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |     Column2
| 2  | 2   |    x    |    y    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |     Column2
| 3  | 1   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    | Column4,Column6
| 3  | 2   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    y    |    x    |    y    |    x    | Column4,Column6
| 4  | 1   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    y    |     Column7
| 4  | 2   |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |     Column7
```

Regards,
Bruno

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBmUd.png)

Comment: Do you have a fixed # of columns to check or are you looking for a more generalizable solution to allow for any number of columns?

Comment: A more generalizable solution would be better, but I think a simpler one considering 20 columns would solve my problem.

Comment: Check out [lead](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lead) and [lag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (ignore the WITH statement, it's in order to reproduce your table):

```
WITH sample AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS Day, "x" AS Column1, "x" AS Column2, "x" AS Column3, "x" AS Column4, "x" AS Column5, "x" AS Column6, "x" AS Column7
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, "x", "x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x"
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, "x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, "x", "x", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x"
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y"
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"

)

SELECT ID,
    Day,
    STRING_AGG(column_name) AS modified_columns
FROM (SELECT ID, 
    value,
    Day,
    LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, column_name ORDER BY Day) AS previous_value,
    column_name
FROM
(SELECT * FROM sample
UNPIVOT(value FOR column_name IN (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7)))
)
WHERE value <> previous_value
GROUP BY ID, Day
```

Details of the process:

1. Unpivotting the table (Brand new unpivot function !)

```
SELECT * FROM sample
UNPIVOT(value FOR column_name IN (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7))
```

[image]

2. Compute previous day value for each column and each ID:

```
SELECT ID, 
    value,
    Day,
    LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, column_name ORDER BY Day) AS previous_value,
    column_name
FROM
(SELECT * FROM sample
UNPIVOT(value FOR column_name IN (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7)))
```

[image]

3. Aggregate modified column names for each ID and Day

The overall query gives you

[image]

NB: the unpivot operation makes it easy to generalise, you should be able to get the list of your columns with

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM yourdataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = yourtablename
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ("ID", "Day")
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer in order to close the question (if the answer is satisfying)

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select * except(prev_row, cur_row),
  (
    select ifnull(string_agg(col_name),'no changes')
    from (
      select * from unnest(split(prev_row)) p,
      unnest([struct(split(p, ':')[offset(0)] as col_name, split(p, ':')[safe_offset(1)] as value_previous)])
    )
    join (
      select * from unnest(split(cur_row)) c,
      unnest([struct(split(c, ':')[offset(0)] as col_name, split(c, ':')[safe_offset(1)] as value_current)]) 
    )
    using(col_name)
    where value_previous != value_current
    and not col_name in ('id', 'day')
  ) as changes_vs_previous_day
from (
  select *,
    translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', '') cur_row,
    translate(to_json_string(lag(t) over(partition by id order by day)), '{}"', '') prev_row,
  from `project.dataset.table` t
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Update: below is slightly refactored version of above just to make it less verbose

```
#standardSQL
create temp function extract_name_value_pairs (row string) as (
  array(
    select as struct * from unnest(split(translate(row, '{}"', ''))) t,
    unnest([struct(split(t, ':')[offset(0)] as col_name, split(t, ':')[safe_offset(1)] as value)])
  )  
);
select * except(prev_row, cur_row),
  (
    select ifnull(string_agg(col_name),'no changes')
    from unnest(extract_name_value_pairs(prev_row)) p
    join unnest(extract_name_value_pairs(cur_row)) c
    using(col_name)
    where p.value != c.value
    and not col_name in ('id', 'day')
  ) as changes_vs_previous_day
from (
  select *,
    to_json_string(t) as cur_row,
    to_json_string(lag(t) over(partition by id order by day)) as prev_row,
  from `project.dataset.table` t
)
```